# How are three satellites sufficient to find a unique point in GPS? What happens in case of an overlap?

Tags: geometry, satellites, gps

[image]

Is it because the 2nd and 3rd satellites' centres are collinear? How is satellite overlapping avoided? If not avoided then what happen to the signal sent from an overlapped satellite?This is just a 2D representation. Same concept can be applied in 3d.

Comment: The three satellites should not be one a line. Then there will be never be an issue.

Comment: @Steeven So how does scientist manage that two satellites dont overlap?

Comment: I'm quite sure that a gps receives signals from 6-8 satellites or more to be accurate. Also, you know the satellite location and should be able to simply calculate if they are in line. I'm no expert here, though - this question might get better answers on Engineering SE

Comment: I would VTC as an engineering topic  and also because there is plenty of scope for self research, at all levels.

Comment: This is mathematics (or engineering for the practical issues) not physics.

Comment: Although 3 sats are enough, seeing 4 improves the positioning _significantly_. Note, the GPS receiver *doesn't see the position of the satellites*, it only gets their *timestamps* (with nanosecond precision, which is a quite funny thing because here already the General Relativity should be also compensated). I don't know, how exactly it works. Ask this on the Engineering SE.

Comment: Related: [Why does GPS positioning require four satellites?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/12866)

Answer (score 1):

The physics story is that there are 3 equations and three unknowns. Except for degenerate geometries you can then solve the equations. In practical terms they typically need a fourth one to time synch also, i.e. a 4th variable.

The accuracy analysis is complicated, and has a lot of factors. See below. One of the factors was recognized early as the relativistic time effects. See this below also.

The detailed story is covered well enough for your question in references below. But the overall idea is straightforward.

Receivers are typically 4 or more channels, and if more it reduces the errors. The error, or inaccuracies on estimating location are multiple, but mostly two: the inherent measurement error, the time measurement uncertainty, and that is proportional to the inverse bandwidth and the sqrt of the signal to noise ratio. The other large factor is the geometric dilution, I.e., the geometrical factors because it's usually not the optimal geometry, even if they can choose from 6 or 8 channels.

The channels are determined by the spread spectrum code - all at the same frequency (for say the C/A signal). Precision and military codes are longer and provide more bandwidth and thus accuracy, and more security and anti jam. You can see most of this in the wiki article on GPS.

A point that also reduces to physics is the freq shift due to relativity. There's two factors that come in, one the special relativistic Doppler shift where time dilates, and the gravitational potential opposite shift (due to general relativity and the different gravitational potential of the satellite locations and the clocks at the earth surface). You can derive both from general relativity with one clock in motion in the higher gravitational potential. THeres some real fine points in all tHese, but those are the basics. The total relativistic effect is a net speed up of the clocks in orbit (at this altitude, lower like at the ISS it's still a slowdown). Since they were calculated they are offset in the clocks or freq synthesizers in orbit (the freqs adjusted). See the details in the Living Teviews article below. An interesting point, when first launched the engineers didn't really believe the GR effect was real, but the physicists insisted, and they did not offset the frequencies (i.e. The clocks), but provided a w any where they could be varied just enough JUST IN CASE it might happen. So they did.

See some discussion and derivations in a physics (teaching) journal at https://www.aapt.org/doorway/TGRU/articles/Ashbyarticle.pdf

For those who think this is not physics see it in Living Reviews in Relativity at http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2003-1&page=articlese5.html

See a summary of the error analysis to see more details at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System

The wiki article at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System